# transform does not work with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carousel 2.
I want to transform Owl-Stage to right when mouse is over.
It works in CSS.

```
.owl-stage:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1280px, 0, 0) !important;
    transform: translate3d(-1280px, 0, 0) !important;
    transition: 450ms transform, 450ms -webkit-transform;
}
```

Since translate3d value (-1280px) is changed by owl carousel dynamically.
I need to check with jQuery.

```
    $('.owl-stage').hover(function () {
        console.log('stage overed');

        normalanimation = $(this).css('transform').split(',')[4];
        var animation = parseInt(normalanimation) + (-112);
        console.log(animation);
        //$(this).transition({ x: '-40px' });
        $(this).css({ "transform": "translate3d(" +animation+ "px, 0, 0) !important;", "transition": "transform 450ms"});
    });
```

I used many other ways such style atrr. but no luck.
Or jQuery doesn't support css transform?

Comment: Can you try using toggle class instead of inline styling? http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: What does `animation` prints out in console? What you see in DOM attribute?

Comment: @SyedFarhan I can't use toggle class since translate3d value is set dynamically by owl carousel when I click on nav buttons or drag item.

Comment: @Justinas animation is numeric value. It is correct. I want to move owl-stage by this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the `.css()` method and `"!important"` jQuery just doesn't understand it correctly so it gets ignored.

Try updating using the .attr() method instead

```
$(this).attr("style", "transform:translate3d(" +animation+ "px, 0, 0)!important; transition:transform 450ms");
```

Comment: Thanks. but it overwrites original attributes of  owl-stage. Is it possible to modify transform value only?

Comment: ok so first get the existing styles and append the new ones.
eg: $(this).attr("style", $(this).attr("style")+";transform:translate3d(" +animation+ "px, 0, 0)!important; transition:transform 450ms");